# How to return a map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am wondering how to define a function, which will return a map. Now I have two auxiliary functions. 
One is :

```
(string->ascii str)
```

which can convert a string into an ascii code, like:

```
user=> (string->ascii "ouch")
(79 85 67 72)
user=> (string->ascii "gulp")
(71 85 76 80)
```

the other function is:

```
(ascii->num96 seq)
```

which can convert a list into a decimal, like:

```
user=> (ascii-num96 '(79 85 67 72))
70684008
user=> (ascii-num96 '(71 85 76 80))
63606992
```

Now, I need to define a function "make-dict" calling these two functions together and returning a map. The result should be:

```
user=> (make-dict ["ouch" "gulp"])
{"ouch" 70684008, "gulp" 63606992}
```

I wrote some code, but it does not work, like:

```
(defn make-dict [vector]
(map (ascii-num96 #(string-ascii %)) vector))
```

Is there anyone who can teach how to get the result like this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```clj
(defn make-dict [words]
  (zipmap words (map (comp ascii-num96 string->ascii) words)))
```

You basically take 2 seqs -- `words` and `(map (comp ascii-num96 string->ascii) words)` -- and zip them up into a map.

Comment: Got you! Thank you so much!  I have one more question, if the number of elements in `words` does not match the number of elements in `(map (comp ascii-num96 string->ascii) words)` , will it zipmap successfully?  Thank you!

Comment: Can you think of a scenario where `xs` would have a different length than `(map f xs)`?

Comment: Ditto what @amalloy said.  But let's assume an unrelated scenario -- if you have 2 input seqs, `xs` and `ys`, then just like `map`, the `zipmap` function stops consuming the input seqs after the shortest seq has been fully consumed ( after `(min (count xs) (count ys))` elements).

Answer (score 3):

Or without `zipmap`:

```
(into {} (map vector names (map (comp ascii-num96 string->ascii) names)))
```

Two things going on might be of interest, kind of 'tricks'. One is that you can use `map` with many input sequences, your 'mapping function' just needs to be able to handle the same number of arguments. Here the mapping function is `vector`, which takes a word and a number and puts them together, like this: ["gulp" 34234].

The other thing is that the function `into` interprets a vector as a key / value pair.